# Efficient Data Structure to aggregate data along multiple columns

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

Suppose I have data with 100 columns and I want to support (aggregate)queries on 70 of those 100 columns, whats best data structure I can use here:

Example:
5 columns (studentGender, studentClass, studentGrade, studentAttendanceGrade, studentCoin)

and Now I want to support 3 aggregate queries of type:

1. sum of studentCoins by studentGrade
2. sum of studentCoins by studentClass
3. sum of studentCoins by studentGender

Please don't provide SQL solution, I am talking about C program with data structure and input(vector of size 5) is coming in real time and I may not store raw granular data unless some efficient solution exist.

One solution is to maintain 3 hashTables one for each query type. 
But this solution is difficult to extend because in future if we support 100 columns and 70 queries then in that case we need to maintain 70 hashTables one for each query type

Comment: Can you describe your hashTables solution properly?

Comment: If updates are dominated by queries, keep the results for frequent queries up to date. _If_ attribute values are not likely to be really infrequent, iterating arrays may be good enough (consider coding _many_ attributes into "machine words" in a way that is easy to mask (_bit fields_)).

Comment: If you're "talking about C program", why have you tagged this C++? Someone might bother to write up an answer using [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), which you then couldn't use...

Comment: Are the sums for all of the data or can it be any subset?

Answer (score 0):

I find your question very broad, and may be apt for close votes, however, to give some ideas:

The main question for me is, "how many rows are we talking about?" If the data comes in at high rates in real-time, with only occasional queries, then separate the receiving of the data (to flat file e.g.) and the processing of this data (reading the flat files).

Another solution, if the queries are all predetermined, is to process the data on-the-fly while coming in.

Hash tables and balanced trees can be an option if the queries are more dynamical.